# How to extract LineString data from GeoDataFrame and match with Polygon?

Tags: python, geopandas

Dear StackOverflow community,

Main question:

I have a GeoDataFrame containing the StreetNetwork of NYC - Manhattan (obtained through the osmnx package), where I would like to extract the coordinates (lon/lat data) from all streets which are stored as LineStrings under geometry, like so:

*

```
field_1                                                     0
access                                                       
bridge                                                       
geometry    LINESTRING (-73.9975944 40.7140611, -73.997492...
highway                                           residential
junction                                                     
key                                                         0
lanes                                                        
length                                                 11.237
maxspeed                                               25 mph
name                                         Catherine Street
oneway                                                   True
osmid                                                 5670536
ref                                                          
service                                                      
tunnel                                                       
u                                                  1773060097
v                                                    42437559
width                                                        
geometry    LINESTRING (-73.9975944 40.7140611, -73.997492...
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

*

What I am trying to do is to extract the geometry information for each line-item:

`df.iloc[x][3]`

The issue is that the output format is as str:

```
[1]: LINESTRING (-73.9975944 40.7140611, -73.9974922 40.7139962)
[2]: print(type(...))
[2]: <class 'str'>
```

This makes it hard to automate and process the output data. Does anyone know how to extract it so that it is already in LineString (or any other useable list/array) format?

Further question:

My overall goal is to map this street information with a shapefile for taxi zones (zones in the format of polygons) to identify which streets are in which zone, and which lon/lat areas are covered with streets within one zone (polygon). Is there any straight forward way to do this leveraging shapely, geopandas or osmnx packages (i.e. something like "*polygon.contains(Point)*" but in the sense of "*polygon.contains(LineString)*"?

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a column of Polygons from string to GeoPandas geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433138/converting-a-column-of-polygons-from-string-to-geopandas-geometry)

Answer (score 1):

For extraction coordinates of geometry you need to use the following code:

```py
df.geometry.apply(lambda geom: geom.coords, axis=1)
```